# Are there health or sportive benefits (or negatives) of apnea training?

Tags: breathing, apnea-holding-breath

Many people regard apnea achievements as a sport.

Apnea training mainly reduces sensitivity to CO2 levels. Is it beneficial except when in cases of voluntary or involuntary air deprivation? Will it have any effect for health/sport when breathing is not limited? Or possible negatives?

The other part is deep relaxation when lowering the oxygen demand. Can we say how long do you have to hold your breath in order to activate this part (as in the first stages of the training you deal mainly with CO2 sensitivity)?